# What happened to the bullets inside a human with Ajin ability?

Tags: ajin-demi-human

I am relatively up-to-date with the manga (have read up to around chapter 40-50). I don't remember what chapter exactly, but this scene happened when Sato used a plane to bomb the building. As he confronted the S.W.A.T team, he got shot right through his head with bullets many times, after which his Ajin ability would automatically regenerate his body with the bullets still inside his head.

How could his Ajin regenerate his body while the bullets were still inside his head?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Mass conversion, perhaps? So the bullet is absorbed into the body.

Comment: We see a part where Sato goes to kill a CEO. He cuts off his hand and uses the regeneration power to burn a hole through the thick door in order to get to the guy. Presumably the bullets in his head are an obstruction, and thus would be disintegrated just like the door was.